# Retrieve enum by its given value, not the KEY

Tags: kotlin

I don't know the terminology so I don't know where to look (sorry).
Here my enum:

```
enum class QualityGrade(val grade: Int) {
    GOOD(1), OK(2), SOSO(3), BAD(4)
}
```

What I want to do (somehow)

```
assertEquals(QualityGrade.GOOD, QualityGrade(1))
```

I don't have the words to describe this problem, so I hope someone can answer that...

Comment: Don't forget you can just do ``assertEquals(QualityGrade.GOOD.value, 1)``. I know you might be asking for a more general "check this set of constructor parameters generates this instance", but that's literally how an enum is defined - so your test is sort of duplicating your enum code and checking it's still identical, rather than validating the enum's final behaviour and properties. That's why it's awkward to do what you want, it's not the way you use an enum or how you'd normally approach testing it

Comment: The assertion here is just because of my missing words. In the end I need a full back-and-forth mapping like provided below, needing to refer to a value, and get the enum, and refer to the enum, getting the value.
@augur's answer works fine; Maybe a cooler Kotlin way exists to fulfill this requirement? I'm a beginner still in that language.

Comment: I usually do lookups the same way as @augur, stash a copy of ``values()`` (or something derived from it) in a companion object, which is like having a ``static`` member if you like. Just so you avoid creating a new array each time you call ``values``. You could use ``values().associateBy { it.grade }`` to generate the map but it's the same deal!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is approach I typically use in such cases:

```
enum class QualityGrade(val grade: Int) {
    GOOD(1), OK(2), SOSO(3), BAD(4);

    companion object {
        private val valuesByGrade = values().map {
            it.grade to it
        }.toMap()

        fun findByGrade(grade: Int): QualityGrade? {
            return valuesByGrade[grade]
        }
    }
}

assert(QualityGrade.GOOD == QualityGrade.findByGrade(1))
```

UPD: reworked to slightly better version

Comment: you could also use `private val valuesByGrade = values().associateBy(QualityGrade::grade)` to create the map, instead of `.map{}` and then `.toMap()`.